# Table per Class hierarchy - get only Superclass with Criteria API, discriminator not working?

Tags: java, hibernate, hierarchy, hibernate-criteria

I have `Table per Class` hierarchy with 3 classes, `Academy`:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "academy")
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
@DiscriminatorColumn(
        name="hibernate_hierarchy_discriminator",
        discriminatorType=DiscriminatorType.STRING
)
@DiscriminatorValue(value="ACADEMY")
public class Academy {
//
}
```

Class `Institute`, which extends `Academy`:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "institute")
@DiscriminatorValue(value="INSTITUTE")
public class Institute extends Academy{
//
}
```

And class `Department`, which extends `Instutute`:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "department")
@DiscriminatorValue(value="DEPARTMENT")
public class Department extends Institute{
//
}
```

And when I save particular entities, it looks OK - for example I see *discriminator* column. But when I save one `Academy`, one `Institute` and one `Department` - and I try to get only Academies, I got 3 elements but I expect only one - list contains not only `Academy` but also `Institute` and `Department`. I created a unit test which shows what I mean:

```
@Test
@Transactional
public void test_WhenOneAcademyIsSaved_OneAcademyShouldBeRead() throws Exception {
    //tables are empty before test

    final Academy academy = new Academy("Michigan", "Main street");
    getCurrentSession().save(academy);
    final Institute institute = new Institute("Michigan", "Main street", "IT", "C", academy);
    getCurrentSession().save(institute);
    getCurrentSession().save(new Department("Michigan", "Main street", "IT", "C", "333 333 333", "Programming", institute));

    List<Academy> academies = (List<Academy>)getCurrentSession()
        .createCriteria(Academy.class)
        .list();
    assertEquals(1, academies.size()); //size is 3
}
```

(This is also tree structure and `Academy` has a list of `Instutute`s, and `Institute` has a list of `Department`s, bu I think it does not matter in my problem). I thought that *discriminator* column cares about distinguishing between different class instances and if I create Criteria for `Academy`, I will get only Academies. Is there a solution to get only base class instances with Criteria API when `Table per Class` hierarchy is used?

Comment: Well, that's the principle of inheritance: it defines an *is a* relationship. Institute *is a* Academy. So when you query academies, you get institutes. That's expected. Side note: why do you specify SINGLE_TABLE as inheritance strategy, if what you want is a table per class?

Comment: @JB Nizet I fix it to TABLE_PER_CLASS. Do you mean that what I try to do is impossible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved it in this way:
Because I need to distinguish between parent entity `Academy` and child entity `Institute` I decided to remove explicite inheritance. Instead, I create `BaseAcademy` class from which `Academy` inherits and `BaseInstitute` from which `Institute` inherits. Now, there is no "Hibernate" inheritance, but `BaseInstitute` class inherits from `BaseAcademy`. I don't know if it is good solution, but at this moment everything works.

Answer (score 0):

You do not require `@DiscriminatorValue` for TABLE_PER_CLASS inheritance strategy since a new table is created for each sub class. Please note that the descriminator is required when you use SINGLE_TABLE or JOINED inheritance strategies. The descriminator column above cases helps hibernate distinguish between different sub classes when fetching data from the single or common table.